# Codewars - Delete occurrences of an element if it occurs more than n times

Tags: javascript

I just completed [this challenge](https://www.codewars.com/kata/delete-occurrences-of-an-element-if-it-occurs-more-than-n-times/python) on Codewars.

I have completed the question with my own method, but can someone explain to me the Best Practice answer. Can somehow explain how this code functions?

```
function deleteNth(arr,x) {
  var cache = {};
  return arr.filter(function(n) {
    cache[n] = (cache[n]||0) + 1;
    return cache[n] <= x;
  });
}
```

I did this:

```
function deleteNth(arr,n){
  var count = 0;
  //loop backwards so it removes duplicates from the right
  for(let i= arr.length; i > 0; i--){
    for(let j=0; j < arr.length; j++){
      if (arr[i] == arr[j]){
        count += 1
      }
    }
    if(count > n){
      arr.splice(i,1);
      i = arr.length;
    }
        count = 0;
  }
  return arr;  
}
```

Comment: Could you show us your solution?

Comment: Your `predicate` count the number of occurence and return `true` if it's not too high.
`return true` mean you want to keep the element in the array.

Comment: [edit] ...  ... code in comments is unreadable...

Comment: Can you add the codewars question too. The function name is quite misleading.

Answer (score 2):

This is how the first code works. It is a quite nice solution and quite easy to read if you understand the filter function.

```js
function deleteNth(arr, x) {
  // Create an empty object to store how many times each object exists
  var cache = {};
  // Call the filter function, the delegate is called once for each item
  // in the array and you return true or false depending on if it should
  // be kept or not
  return arr.filter(function(n) {
    // Use the item as key and store the number of times the item has appeared.
    // (cache[n]||0) fetches the current value of cache[n] or zero if it doesn't
    // exist. Then add one to it and store it.
    cache[n] =(cache[n]||0) + 1;
    // If the number of times it has appeared in the array is less or equal to
    // the limit then return true so the filter function keeps it.
    return cache[n] <= x;
  });
}
```